# Doing count and splitting in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Hi guys need some advice on what other possible way is there to achieve the below result

(Before)

```sh
    02-10-2019 name_AA_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_AA_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_BB_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_BB_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_CC_xxxxx.txt
```

(After)

```sh
    02-10-2019 name_AA_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_AA_xxxxx.txt  
    Count : 2  

    02-10-2019 name_BB_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_BB_xxxxx.txt  
    count : 2  

    02-10-2019 name_CC_xxxxx.txt  
    Count 1
```

Assumption

- please assume `name` is same for all file
- identifier for all filename is the `AA,BB,CC` in actual file there will be a name for each of them, actual file format is COMPANYNAME_TYPENAME_*.txt
- TYPENAME will change

Tried to grep and pipe it into WC it will work but its not efficient and i cant reuse the code, did a bit of search and was thinking of using `awk` command but not sure how i can execute that.

A quick fix im using now is `cat input.file | grep TYPENAME` for the name and then use `cat input.file | grep TYPENAME | wc -l` to check the count

any advice would be appreciated.

PS: as i do not wish to leak any sensitive information therefore am trying to provide as much information as i can.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have mentioned you have tried grep and WC, please do mention those efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, once you add your efforts will undo it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

`awk 'prev!=$2 && count{print "Count : " count;count=""} {count++;prev=$2} END{if(count){print "Count : " count}}'  Input_file`

With Jnzz' updated input file:

`awk -F '  +|_' 'prev!=$3 && count{print "Count : " count;count=""; print ""} {count++;prev=$3; print} END{if(count){print "Count : " count}}' Input_file`

Output:

```
    02-10-2019 name_AA_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_AA_xxxxx.txt  
Count : 2

    02-10-2019 name_BB_xxxxx.txt  
    02-10-2019 name_BB_xxxxx.txt  
Count : 2

    02-10-2019 name_CC_xxxxx.txt  
Count : 1
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help , tired to run the code however did not get the result, also i notice might not have written the question more clearly, ill be editing - sorry bout it

Comment: With GNU awk. A small addition to RavinderSingh13's code:  `awk -F '  +|_' 'prev!=$2 && count{print "Count : " count;count=""; print ""} {count++;prev=$2; print} END{if(count){print "Count : " count}}'  file`

Comment: hi @Cyrus thanks for the input, i have edited the question so its clearer, sorry just started usings SO, normally use SO for my own research only never actually posted any question before so might not have posted it clearly

Comment: @Jnzz: Switch in my example from $2 to $3 with your new input file.

Comment: @Cyrus, thank you sir, would like to request you if you could add your solution Tomy post too sir, since I am operating from mobile last 2 days, couldn't copy it. Will be grateful.

Comment: @Cyrus hey thanks, it worked. got what i needed, let me understand the code ill chat you up if im having any problem if you dont mind.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I've updated your answer. No problem. To Jnzz: you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort input.file | uniq -c | awk '/name.*/{for (i = 1; i <= $1; ++i) print $3; print "Count : "$1}'
```

Or if you need especially print particularly for **count 1**:

```
sort input.file | uniq -c | awk '/name.*/{for (i = 1; i <= $1; ++i) print $3; if ($1>1) printf "Count : "; else printf "Count "; print $1; }'
```

Comment: hi thanks for the input , i think uniq works, am looking into it now, anyway i might not have phrase the question clear i will be editing the question